How do I get the output of the Join Strings node in python?
I'm trying to get the output from as join strings node with the following code but it's printing out nothing?
My Nodes

Code
import bpy

nodeTree = bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes"].nodes

stringOutput = nodeTree["Join Strings"].outputs[0]

print(stringOutput.default_value)


AFAIK you can't get evaluated outputs from nodes (strings, at least), but in this case you can parse the nodes that are linked to the input of the join strings node and read their default values

Right now only way to take string from geometry nodes evaluation process is to read name of geometry attributes. Exactly, with length limit.
